# MIPS How Do I Multiply A Float By An Integer And Store It As A Float?

Tags: mips

I am very new to MIPS. This is the last part of an assignment, I moved the hours worked into $t0 as an int and the hourly rate is stored in $f4 as a float. I can't multiply them due to the data type difference, Do I have To completely re-write a part?

Just to clarify, I am just now learning this and I apologize for odd formatting or the basic coding logic.

```
.data
    namePrompt: .asciiz "\n Please Enter Your Name: \n"
    helloMSG: .asciiz "\n Hello, Welcome To The Program, "
    
    hoursPrompt: .asciiz "\n Please Enter Number Of Hours Worked This Week: \n"
    hoursMSG: .asciiz "\n This Week You Have Worked This Many Hours: "
    
    ratePrompt: .asciiz "\n Please Enter Your Hourly Rate In Format (xx.xx): \n"
    rateMSG: .asciiz "\n You Have An Hourly Rate Of : $"

    finalMSG: .asciiz "\n Your Paycheck Amount For This Week Is: $ "
    
    name: .space 20
    rate: .float 0.0
    paycheck: .float 0.0 
.text
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, namePrompt
    syscall # Displays Message To Ask User For Name
    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, name
    li $a1, 20
    syscall # Stores Name As Text
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, helloMSG
    syscall # Displays Message That Says Hello To User
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, name
    syscall # Displays Name
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, hoursPrompt
    syscall #Displays Message That Asks User For Hours Worked In Week
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t0, $v0                       #Stores Hours Worked Into $t0
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, hoursMSG
    syscall # Displays Message About Hours Worked
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0
    syscall # Display Actual Hours Worked
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, ratePrompt
    syscall #Displays Message That Asks User For Hourly Rate
    lwc1 $f4, rate
    li $v0, 6
    syscall # Allows User To Enter Their Rate
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, rateMSG
    syscall #Displays Message About Hourly Rate
    li $v0, 2
    add.d $f12, $f0, $f4
    syscall #Displays Actual Hourly Rate
    move $t1, $v0                           #Stores Hourly Rate into $t1
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0,finalMSG
    syscall #Displays Message About Final Calculation
    move $s0,$t0
    move $s1,$t1
    mul $t2, $s1, $s0
    li $v0, 2
    move $a0, $2
    syscall
    #This is where I am stuck, I know I have to do something before i try "mul"
```

I have Write a program that will Read Name...print it, Then ask for number of hours worked for one week...then print. Then ask for hourly rate...then prints it Finally it will calculate your paycheck amount.

Comment: We cannot multiply a float by an integer.  But we can convert an integer to a float, and multiply two floats together, the result will be another float.

Comment: @ErikEidt oh okay, sorry to bother but how could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot multiply a float by an integer.  But we can convert an integer to a float, and multiply two floats together, the result will be another float.

There's an instruction to convert an integer to a float — the only catch is that the instruction requires the integer to first be in a floating point register (as an integer).  So, you have to get the raw integer into a floating point register, using a move like `mtc1` (if the value was in an integer register) or a load like `l.s` (if the value was in memory).  These are are literal bit transfers so will work with either float or integer data.

Then use an appropriate form of `cvt`, like `cvt.s.w`, which will convert a 32-bit integer to a 32-bit float.

These work in reverse, too: convert float to integer (still in float register), then transfer that raw value to integer register for further use.

So, fundamentally, it is the floating point registers and instructions that can convert from integer to float and vice versa.

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a shot, to convert integer to float